# Unexpected exit status when using -pass-exit-codes in g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, exit-code

When doing the following, the exit code of the failed compilation is 1, however, based on [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gnat_ug_unx/Auxiliary-Output-Control.html), I would expect it to be >=3. Why is this? What can I do if I want more detailed exit codes than binary success/fail?

```
> echo "int main() {fail}" > fail.cpp
> g++ -pass-exit-codes fail.cpp -o fail
fail.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
fail.cpp:1: error: ‘fail’ was not declared in this scope
fail.cpp:1: error: expected ';' before ‘}’ token
> echo $?
1
> g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.1.3 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-27)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation that you point at belongs to gcc version 3.3.6. However, in version >=4, the documentation for that compiler flag has changed and it now only states:

> -pass-exit-codes 
>           Normally the gcc program exits with the code of 1 if any phase of the compiler returns a non-success return code.  If you specify
>           -pass-exit-codes, the gcc program instead returns with the numerically highest error produced by any phase returning an error
>           indication.  The C, C++, and Fortran front ends return 4 if an internal compiler error is encountered.

Which is a little confusing when reading it. It does not specify the error codes that were well explained in the documentation of 3.x. Then, it is possible that the exit code that you are looking for is not generated any more in version 4.x of gcc/g++.

Comment: Makes sense. Question then is what are the exit codes for version >=4? Did not find them anywhere and could not think of ways to provoke an exit code other than 1 (which I assume must mean "source file could not be compiled").

Comment: Unfortunately, other than exit code 4 (internal compiler error), there seems to be no documentation. If you follow the error codes defined (and overriden) in gcc 4.8.2 source code (in gcc/system.h) the only ones defined are 0, 1 and 4, so I guess that's pretty much it.

Comment: I was looking to differentiate internal g++ errors from source code errors, in particular, I need to identify the following error: `fatal_error (input_location, "had to relocate PCH");` (gcc/gcc-common.c). Based on my quick look at the code, `fatal` would be an exit code of 1, is this correct?

Comment: I think that you are right. In the end it looks like you might be out of luck with exit codes, and for your goal, you will have to parse the compiler text output. Your question was interesting! I upvoted it since it made me look at that compiler option more closely!