# Is there proper documentation for exit codes generated by the gcc compiler flag `-pass-exit-codes`?

Tags: gcc, g++4.8

While answering this question [Unexpected exit status when using -pass-exit-codes in g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889522/unexpected-exit-status-when-using-pass-exit-codes-in-g/), I realized that the documentation for the compiler directive `-pass-exit-codes` is quite obscure:

> -pass-exit-codes
>     Normally the gcc program exits with the code of 1 if any phase of the compiler returns a non-success return code. If you specify -pass-exit-codes, the gcc program instead returns with the numerically highest error produced by any phase returning an error indication. The C, C++, and Fortran front ends return 4 if an internal compiler error is encountered.

Which leads to the question "What are other possible error codes?". If there are other possible error codes, they could be valuable to programmer, so he could use them for compilation automation.

After following the trail of ways in which the exit value is defined and returned in gcc 4.8.2 (https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.2/gcc-4.8.2.tar.bz2), it looks like the only possible exit codes would be `0` (`SUCCESS_EXIT_CODE`), `1` (`FATAL_EXIT_CODE`), and `4` (`ICE_EXIT_CODE`).

Now, in the issue tracking system for gcc development, (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22600#c4) we can see that an initial patch suggested `3` arbitrarily as a return value for ICE-related exit codes. Then someone suggested to use `2`, unless other error code was using `2` already, and that it ended up being assigned to `4` giving no extra comments of why `4` was chosen. Are there then error codes 3 and 4? What are they for?

Since knowing of other exit codes could be beneficial to programmer using gcc/g++. Is there a well documented list of possible exit codes from gcc? If not, it should probably be considered for addition in the documentation by the gcc team.